# C#, is MultiThread Lambda using free variable Valid?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, scope, free-variable

I want to use some free variables in MultiThread Lambda expression.

Here is example,

```
{
   int a = 0;
   Thread t = new Thread(() => 
   {
        SomeBlockingFunc(a);
   });
   t.Start();
}
```

I can't recognize when Thread t Excute, even variable scope is over.

Even after scope is over, is 'int a' Valid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda expression *captures* the `a` variable. This code is entirely valid.

From the draft C# 6 spec, [section 11.16.6.2](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#111662-captured-outer-variables):

> When an outer variable is referenced by an anonymous function, the outer variable is said to have been captured by the anonymous function. Ordinarily, the lifetime of a local variable is limited to execution of the block or statement with which it is associated (§9.2.8). However, the lifetime of a captured outer variable is extended at least until the delegate or expression tree created from the anonymous function becomes eligible for garbage collection.

It's important to differentiate between the *scope* of a variable (which is just the section of code within which the identifier refers to that variable) and the *lifetime* of the variable.

It's also worth noting that it really is still a *variable*. Multiple delegates can potentially capture the same variable. Consider this code:

```cs
using System;

int value = 0;
Action a = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"In first action; value={value}");
    value++;
};
Action b = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"In second action; value={value}");
    value++;
};

a();
a();
b();
a();
```

The output of this is:

```
In first action; value=0
In first action; value=1
In second action; value=2
In first action; value=3
```

As you can see:

- The two actions have captured the same variable
- Changes to the variable value made within each action are seen by both actions

Comment: This answer works for me. I did some tests and I gain confience. Thanks :)